# how to change the font of the number after theorem

Tags: fonts, formatting, theorems

I want to change the font of the number to `\itshape`,
for example, I want to get
Theorem {\itshape 1.1}.
Is there any way to do it in the theorem  environment

Answer (score 6):

Supposing you are only using the `amsthm` package in your document, this is how it can be done.

If you want this behavior only for the "plain" theorem style, add the following lines in your preamble to re-define the plain style:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\th@plain}{%
  \renewcommand\@upn{\textit}%
  \itshape%
}
\makeatother
```

and you're done.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\th@plain}{%
  \renewcommand\@upn{\textit}%
  \itshape%
}
\makeatother

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

\begin{thm}
This is a theorem.
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Instead, if you want this behavior for all theorem styles, replace the above code with

```
\makeatletter
  \renewcommand\@upn{\textit}
\makeatother
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\makeatletter
  \renewcommand\@upn{\textit}
\makeatother

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{rmk}[thm]{Remark}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

\begin{thm}
This is a theorem.
\end{thm}

\begin{rmk}
And this is a remark.
\end{rmk}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way with `ntheorem` package. I redefine the `plain` style:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[amsthm, thmmarks, thref]{ntheorem}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\makeatletter
\renewtheoremstyle{plain}%
{\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ \textit{##2}\theorem@separator]}%
{\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ \textit{##2}\ (##3)\theorem@separator]}
\makeatother
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}

\section{A first section}
\begin{thm}\label{testthm}
This is a test theorem.
\end{thm}
We see in \cref{testthm}…

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you're using no package specialized in theorems, you can do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@opargbegintheorem}{#2}{\textit{#2}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@begintheorem}{#2}{\textit{#2}}{}{}
\makeatother

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\begin{thm}
Something
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```

[image]